# using boost asio to write to carbon gives broken pipe

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, graphite

I have Grafana and Graphite running on localhost.  Everything is setup as default, so the plaintext protocol is configured for port 2003, as described [here](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/feeding-carbon.html)

The following works as desired:

```
export SERVER=localhost
export PORT=2003
echo "no_cluster.fake_xen.sample 25 1488542618" | nc  ${SERVER} ${PORT}
```

Gives me the datapoint I expect (adjust timestamp as needed).

The following minimal compileable example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace basio = boost::asio;

void post_to_carbon (std::string message)
{
    using btcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    constexpr const char* carbon_port="2003";
    basio::io_service ios;
    btcp::resolver resolver(ios);
    btcp::resolver::query query("localhost", carbon_port);
    btcp::endpoint carbon_endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
    btcp::socket sock(ios,carbon_endpoint);
    boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
    basio::write(sock, basio::buffer(message), ignored_error);
    std::cout << "posting: " << message << " gave: " << ignored_error.message() << "\n";

}

int main() {
    post_to_carbon("no_cluster.fake_xen.sample 25 1488542800");
}
```

Fails with the error message:

```
posting: no_cluster.fake_xen.sample 25 1488542800 gave: Broken pipe
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `io_service::run()` is a blocking call. You seem to be using synchronous calls so there's no need for it

Comment: Oops.  That was a hail-mary line I added in while comparing against some examples.  Meant to take it out before pasting the code, and have done so now.  Behavior is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor form `socket(io_service, endpoint)` binds the local endpoint of the socket to the given endpoint.

I think what you want to do is:

```
btcp::socket sock(ios);
sock.connect(carbon_endpoint /* , error_code */);
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  Now I get "connect:  Connection refused."  Any ideas?

Comment: Because the other end isn't listening properly

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but ncat works fine...  Does it do something differently than I am doing?

Comment: ah ok, in which case, see the asio UDP client example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4.html

Comment: Got it.  carbon listens on tcp (else I'd have to use -u for ncat to work right).  The problem is  "localhost" wasn't resolving correctly (anyone know why?).  Changing it to the IP number fixed the connection problem.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: localhost can resolve to any number of ip4/ip6 or hybrid addresses, but typically the ip 4 address will be 127.0.0.1 - if carbon was listening only on the external address then it would not connect. There is a version of `connect()` that takes the resolver iterator as an argument - this will try every address resolved by the resolve call until there is a connection. See the documentation - asio has very sparse documentation but a huge number of hidden gems.